# How to change variant of a button in datable onrowaction lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, button

HTML

```
<lightning-datatable
  data={data}
  columns={col}
  wrap-text-max-lines="2"
  key-field="id"
  class="lowerTable"
  hide-checkbox-column="true"
  enable-infinite-loading="false"
  suppress-bottom-bar
  show-row-number-column="true"
  onrowaction={rowaction}
  data-field="lowerTable"
></lightning-datatable>
```

JS

```
// Table columns
    columns = [ 
        { label: "A", fieldName: "A",  editable: false },
        { label: "B", fieldName: "B",  editable: false },
        { label: "C", fieldName: "C",   editable: false },
        { label: "D", fieldName: "D",  editable: false },
        { label: "Amount", fieldName: "Amount",  editable: true, type: 'currency' },
        { label: 'Select', type: 'lightning-button',typeAttributes: {label: 'Click',variant:base }}];
  
rowaction(event){
event.detail.action.variant='destructive'
}
```

Here I want only selected row to have this change in variant but above code is changing variant to whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved!!!

```
columns = [ 
    { label: "A", fieldName: "A",  editable: false },
    { label: "B", fieldName: "B",  editable: false },
    { label: "C", fieldName: "C",   editable: false },
    { label: "D", fieldName: "D",  editable: false },
    { label: "Amount", fieldName: "Amount",  editable: true, type: 'currency' },
    { label: 'Select', type: 'lightning-button',typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'buttonName'},variant: {fieldName: 'buttonColor'}}}];


rowaction(event){
event.detail.action.variant='destructive'
for(let i in data)
{
if(event.detail.id ==data[i].id){
data[i].buttonColor = 'destructive'
data[i].buttonName = 'Clicked'
}
}
}
```